# How do I programatically add macro definitions and library search paths to an Eclipse CDT project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to programmatically add include paths and macro definitions to a CDT project using the externalSettingsProvider extension point, and I've struggled to find a guide to the basics, so this question is intended to provide that.

So far, I've created a plugin project, in the extensions tab of the plugin xml editor, I add an extension such that the plugin.xml reads as follows:

```xml
    <plugin>
       <extension
             id="my_id"
             name="Settings I want in the project"
             point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.externalSettingsProvider">
          <provider
                class="com.example.MySettingsProvider">
          </provider>
       </extension>
    </plugin>
```

Then I implement the mentioned class. Here's an example of my implementation:

```java
    public class MySettingsProvider extends CExternalSettingProvider {
        @Override
        public CExternalSetting[] getSettings(IProject project, ICConfigurationDescription cfg) {
            final ArrayList<ICSettingEntry> allSettings = new ArrayList<ICSettingEntry>();

            CMacroEntry myMacro = CDataUtil.createCMacroEntry("WINE_CHOICE", "WHITE", ICSettingEntry.NONE);
            allSettings.add( myMacro );

            CIncludePathEntry myInclude = CDataUtil.createCIncludePathEntry("path/to/include", ICSettingEntry.NONE);
            allSettings.add( myInclude );

            final ICSettingEntry[] settings = allSettings.toArray(new ICSettingEntry[allSettings.size()]);
            return new CExternalSetting[]{new CExternalSetting(null, null, null, settings)};
        }
    }
```

This may not be the best way to do this - I am open to feedback for improvement - but I think it should result in some settings that can be added to a CDT project.

This is where I fall down - `getSettings` is never called. I can create a new CDT project, add source files and build them, but if I put a breakpoint in the `getSettings` method, it never gets hit. Perhaps I need to register my provider somewhere? None of the existing sites I found tell you how to get past this point.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked to get `getSettings` to be called:

```java
final IProject project = getTheProjectYouWantToContributeTo();
final ICProjectDescription projectDescription = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescription(project);
final ICConfigurationDescription[] cfgDes = projectDescription.getConfigurations();
for ( final ICConfigurationDescription cfgDe : cfgDes ) {
    String[] idArray = cfgDe.getExternalSettingsProviderIds();
    ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( idArray ));
    boolean idAlreadyPresent = idList.contains( MySettingsProvider.ID );
    if (!idAlreadyPresent ) {
        idList.add( MySettingsProvider.ID );
    }
    idArray = idList.toArray( new String[idList.size()]
    cfgDe.setExternalSettingsProviderIds(idArray);
}
```

When should you call this, and how should you hook it into the project lifecycle? I don't know...